# How to get a count of values in Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am playing around with storing simple Analytics data in Reds.

I'm starting out by storing simple pageview data for a blog post.  I'm using the following model:

`$redis.incr '2014:7:29:post:123:views'`

So i'm storing 'YEAR:MONTH:DAY:ENTITY:ID:ACTION' as the key.

What is the best way to get back the value (sum?) of the keys for all Posts with ID 123?

Ultimately I'd like to be able to create a spark line for the # of views by Day for this Post.

I'm getting the feeling I am approaching this the wrong way.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the count value by `HINCRBY` command rather than `INCR`,
so that you can get all count values of the key by `HGETALL` command.

- For more details, please refer to: http://www.redis.io/commands/hincrby

To increase the count value:

```
$redis.hincrby 'post:123:views' '2014:7:29' 1
```

To get all count values for the key:

```
$redis.hgetall 'post:123:views'
```

Comment: You should explain your answer in a bit more detail, so the questioner knows why it works as well.